# ASP.NET Web application performs slow in client PC

Tags: asp.net, performance, gridview

I am developing a ASP.NET web application. One of my from perform very slow in client machine. Where I use GridView which include some function and some control on there like combo-box input box, each control have some function and calculation on there leave.

```
Please suggest me how can I improve this?

Page on content.

 - GridView
    1. Combobox with jquery datafiltering 
    2. Inputbox with data check function 
    3. More function of grid like update,add, new, delete.

I am also use Viewsate on this page.



<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/UI/Healthcare.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="frmStockIn.aspx.cs" Inherits="Com.Codespecies.Healthcare.UI.Pharmacy.frmStockIn" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder_header" runat="server">




</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
```

...........
....
....

```
            <div class="box_bg" style="height: auto; width: 1020px; border: 0px solid; border-color: #0167AA; margin:5px 0px 0px 0px; float:left;">

                <div style=" min-height:30px; width: 1005px;  padding: 0px 0px 0px 2px;">
                    <div style="min-height: 30px; width:auto; width:300px; float: left; font-weight: bold;">
                        Drugs Details
                    </div>
                    <div style="min-height: 30px; width: 600px; float: left;">
                        <div id="msg" style="height:auto; float:left;">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server" Text=" "></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                        <div id="ajaxLoader" style=" display:none; margin:2px 0px 0px 0px; float:left;">
                            <img height="20px" width="20px" src="../../image/ajax-loading/ajax-loading-2.gif" alt="loader" border="0" style=""/> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div style=" width: auto; padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px;">

                <asp:GridView ID="gvStockIn" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" Width="1020px"
                        AlternatingRowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" AlternatingRowStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderStyle="None" DataKeyNames="ID" 
                        Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
                PageSize="100" ShowFooter="True" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" 
                        onrowcancelingedit="gvStockIn_RowCancelingEdit" onrowcommand="gvStockIn_RowCommand" 
                onrowdeleting="gvStockIn_RowDeleting" onrowediting="gvStockIn_RowEditing" 
                        onrowupdating="gvStockIn_RowUpdating" onrowdatabound="gvStockIn_RowDataBound" 
                        AllowSorting="True" TabIndex="5">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCEEFC" Font-Names="Calibri" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" />

                    <Columns>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SL" SortExpression="ID">
                            <ItemStyle Width="30px" />
                            <HeaderStyle Width="30px" />
                            <FooterStyle Width="30px" />
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblSerialNo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' Width="30px"></asp:Label>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblNewSerialNo" runat="server" Width="30px">NA</asp:Label>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblSerialNo" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>' Width="30px"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Drug" >
                            <ItemStyle Width="170px" />
                            <HeaderStyle Width="170px" />
                            <FooterStyle Width="170px" />
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblDrug" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DRUG_NAME") %>' Width="170px"></asp:Label>
                                <%--<asp:TextBox ID="txtDrug" runat="server" CssClass="Drug" Text='<%# Eval("DRUG_NAME") %>' Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>--%>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>                               
                                <asp:DropDownList CssClass="fire_selected_change_event combobox combobox1" ID="ddlNewDrug" runat="server" onselectedindexchanged="ddlNewDrug_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                </asp:DropDownList>

                                <%--<asp:TextBox ID="txtNewDrug" runat="server" CssClass="Drug" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>--%>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblDrug" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DRUG_NAME") %>' Width="170px"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Presentation">
                            <ItemStyle Width="130px" />
                            <HeaderStyle Width="130px" />
                            <FooterStyle Width="130px" CssClass="drug_list1"/>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblPresentation" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PRESENTATION_NAME") %>' Width="130px"></asp:Label>
                                <%--<asp:TextBox ID="txtPresentation" runat="server" CssClass="Presentation" Text='<%# Eval("PRESENTATION_NAME") %>' Width="110px"></asp:TextBox>--%>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList CssClass="fire_selected_change_event combobox combobox1" ID="ddlNewPresentation" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" onselectedindexchanged="ddlNewPresentation_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                <%--<asp:TextBox ID="txtNewPresentation" runat="server" CssClass="Presentation" Width="110px"></asp:TextBox>--%>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblPresentation" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PRESENTATION_NAME") %>' Width="130px"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Unit Strength">
                            <ItemStyle Width="130px" />
                            <HeaderStyle Width="130px" />
                            <FooterStyle Width="130px" CssClass="drug_list1"/>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblUnitStrength" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DRUG_UNIT_STRENGTH") %>' Width="110px"></asp:Label>
                                <%--<asp:TextBox ID="txtUnitStrength" runat="server" CssClass="UnitStrength" Text='<%# Eval("DRUG_UNIT_STRENGTH") %>' Width="110px"></asp:TextBox>--%>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList CssClass="fire_selected_change_event combobox combobox1" ID="ddlNewUnitStrength" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" onselectedindexchanged="ddlNewUnitStrength_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                <%--<asp:TextBox ID="txtNewUnitStrength" runat="server" CssClass="UnitStrength" Width="110px"></asp:TextBox>--%>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblUnitStrength" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DRUG_UNIT_STRENGTH") %>' Width="110px"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Mfg Date">
                            <ItemStyle Width="65px" />
                            <HeaderStyle Width="65px" />
                            <FooterStyle Width="65px" />
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtManufacturerDate" runat="server" CssClass="date_property" Text='<%# Eval("DRUG_MANUFACTURER_DATE", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>' Height="25px" Width="65px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewManufacturerDate" runat="server" CssClass="date_property" Height="25px" Width="65px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblManufacturerDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DRUG_MANUFACTURER_DATE", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>' Height="25px" Width="65px"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Exp. Date">
                            <ItemStyle Width="65px" />
                            <HeaderStyle Width="65px" />
                            <FooterStyle Width="65px" />
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtExpireDate" runat="server" CssClass="date_property" Text='<%# Eval("DRUG_EXPIRE_DATE", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>' Height="25px" Width="65px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewExpireDate" runat="server" CssClass="date_property" Height="25px"  Width="65px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblExpireDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DRUG_EXPIRE_DATE", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>' Height="25px" Width="65px"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Qty">
                            <ItemStyle Width="40px" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                            <HeaderStyle Width="40px" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                            <FooterStyle Width="40px" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" CssClass="check_decimal Quantity" Text='<%# Eval("QUANTITY") %>' Height="25px" Width="40px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewQuantity" runat="server" CssClass="check_decimal Quantity" Height="25px" Width="40px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblQuantity" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("QUANTITY") %>' Height="25px" Width="40px"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cost Price">
                            <ItemStyle Width="70px" HorizontalAlign="Right"/>
                            <HeaderStyle Width="70px" HorizontalAlign="Right"/>
                            <FooterStyle Width="70px" HorizontalAlign="Right"/>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCostPrice" runat="server" CssClass="check_decimal CostPrice" Text='<%# Eval("COST_PRICE") %>' ontextchanged="txtCostPrice_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" Height="25px" Width="60px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewCostPrice" runat="server" CssClass="check_decimal CostPrice" ontextchanged="txtNewCostPrice_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" Height="25px" Width="60px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblCostPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("COST_PRICE") %>' Height="25px" Width="60px"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sale Price">
                            <ItemStyle Width="70px" HorizontalAlign="Right"/>
                            <HeaderStyle Width="70px" HorizontalAlign="Right"/>
                            <FooterStyle Width="70px" HorizontalAlign="Right"/>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSellPrice" runat="server" CssClass="check_decimal SellPrice" Text='<%# Eval("SELL_PRICE") %>' Height="25px" Width="60px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewSellPrice" runat="server" CssClass="check_decimal SellPrice" Height="25px" Width="60px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblSellPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SELL_PRICE") %>' Height="25px" Width="60px"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Discount">
                            <ItemStyle Width="60px" HorizontalAlign="Right"/>
                            <HeaderStyle Width="60px" HorizontalAlign="Right"/>
                            <FooterStyle Width="60px" HorizontalAlign="Right"/>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDiscount" runat="server" CssClass="check_decimal percentage" Text='<%# Eval("DISCOUNT") %>' Height="25px" Width="60px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewDiscount" runat="server" CssClass="check_decimal percentage" Height="25px" Width="60px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblDiscount" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DISCOUNT") %>' Height="25px" Width="60px"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sub Total">
                            <ItemStyle Width="70px" HorizontalAlign="Right"/>
                            <HeaderStyle Width="70px" HorizontalAlign="Right"/>
                            <FooterStyle Width="70px" HorizontalAlign="Right"/>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSubTotal" runat="server" CssClass="check_decimal" Text='<%# Eval("SUB_TOTAL_AMOUNT") %>' ontextchanged="txtSubTotal_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" Height="25px" Width="70px"></asp:TextBox>
                                <%--<asp:Label ID="lblSubTotal" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SUB_TOTAL_AMOUNT") %>' Height="25px" Width="80px"></asp:Label>--%>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewSubTotal" runat="server" CssClass="check_decimal" Text='' ontextchanged="txtNewSubTotal_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" Height="25px" Width="70px"></asp:TextBox>
                                <%--<asp:Label ID="lblSubTotal" runat="server" Text='' Height="25px" Width="80px"></asp:Label>--%>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblSubTotal" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SUB_TOTAL_AMOUNT") %>' Height="25px" Width="70px"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" ShowHeader="False">
                            <ItemStyle Width="100px" HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
                            <HeaderStyle Width="100px" HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
                            <FooterStyle Width="100px" HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:ImageButton ID="lnkUpdate"    ToolTip="Update"  runat="server" OnClientClick="load_ajax_drugs_details();" ImageUrl="../../image/update.png" Height="25px" Width="25px" CausesValidation="False"  CommandArgument="" CommandName="Update" ></asp:ImageButton>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="lnkCancel"    ToolTip="Cancel"  runat="server" OnClientClick="load_ajax_drugs_details();" ImageUrl="../../image/cancel.png" Height="25px" Width="25px" CausesValidation="False"  CommandArgument="" CommandName="Cancel" ></asp:ImageButton>
                            <%--    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkUpdate" runat="server"   CausesValidation="False" OnClientClick="load_ajax_drugs_details();" CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCancel" runat="server"  CausesValidation="False" OnClientClick="load_ajax_drugs_details();" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>--%>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="lnkNew"    ToolTip="New"  runat="server" OnClientClick="load_ajax_drugs_details();" ImageUrl="../../image/add.png" Height="25px" Width="25px" CausesValidation="False"  CommandArgument="" CommandName="New" ></asp:ImageButton>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="lnkRefresh"    ToolTip="Refresh"  runat="server" OnClientClick="load_ajax_drugs_details();" ImageUrl="../../image/refresh.png" Height="25px" Width="25px" CausesValidation="False"  CommandArgument="" CommandName="Refresh" ></asp:ImageButton>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="lnkEdit"    ToolTip="Edit"  runat="server" OnClientClick="load_ajax_drugs_details();" ImageUrl="../../image/edit.png" Height="25px" Width="25px" CausesValidation="False"  CommandArgument="" CommandName="Edit" ></asp:ImageButton>
                                <%--<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" ToolTip="Edit"  runat="server" OnClientClick="load_ajax_drugs_details();" ImageUrl="../../image/edit.png" Height="10px" Width="15px" CausesValidation="False"  CommandArgument="" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>--%>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="lnkDelete"    ToolTip="Delete"  runat="server" OnClientClick="load_ajax_drugs_details();" ImageUrl="../../image/delete.png" Height="25px" Width="25px" CausesValidation="False"  CommandArgument="" CommandName="Delete" ></asp:ImageButton>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>                   

                    </Columns>

                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                <RowStyle Font-Names="Calibri" /> 
                <FooterStyle CssClass="drug_list"></FooterStyle>
                </asp:GridView> 

                </div>

               .....
               .....

          </ContentTemplate>
          </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>


</asp:Content>



   }
```

Comment: How much data do you have in your controls?

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of reasons for this issue.As far as i under stood from your question I will suggest some places where you need to take a look at.

1)Check how much data you retrieves from database in order to show the gridview primarily.

2)adding the above controls to the gridview won't make it perform badly.But the calculations you where talking about may be a cause.Take a deep look at the code ,check whether there is any long running loops or some thing else is there.

3)if the first two is not helping you make a profiling.For your problem you just need a trial version of [ants performance profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/).
After installing the profile find out which database call or .net function is taking more time to execute then debug it.

Comment: Hi I forget to note that I am use viewstate . Is this any effect on that issue.

Comment: at first you have to tell me how much data is there on your grid-view?